# Uploading file From Java Client Using PHP is not working

Tags: java, php, http

I have the following uploader method in Java:

```
public void uploadFile() throws IOException
{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl/uploadper.php");
File file = new File("C:/Users/mislam/Desktop/perfimg/0.jpg");
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);
httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

I have the following php file

```
    <?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

I am getting the following output

```
executing request POST http://reactor.ctre.iastate.edu/uploadper.php 

HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
```

Which indicates that the communication with the Server was successful but it couldn't upload. What can be the reason that PHP is not uploading the file? Is there any problem in java code?

**EDIT**
After Rewriting code for multipart entity I get the file in the server But uploads operation is not working:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .addBinaryBody("userfile", file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName())
    .build();
    httppost.setEntity(httpEntity);
```

Comment: Start with `print_r($_FILES['userfile'])`

Comment: Its showing nothing. I wonder why!!

Answer (score 1):

First I would have a look at the value of $_FILES['userfile']['error']

See this manual page for description of error codes:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Can you get the raw http request? It may be malformed. One thing to check is the content-type header. If it is not correct php wont see the file. It should be: Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: Its showing Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=YjiAoTjQY6yMFjEStp8ryIbHHeF_9BPAova4d3Jb; charset=US-ASCII

Comment: Using the command System.out.println(mpEntity.getContentType());

Comment: So that's from the client but what is the server getting?